# can there be winspy in running java jvm?

Tags: java, windows

is there something like winspy in java?

I want to change the property or know the property of object (on screen eg swing textbox) from another running jvm?

thxs

Comment: I would change the question to what you actually want to achieve rather than focusing on a complete commercial application suite called "winspy".

Comment: I meant if there is a way to monitor running messages and user interface properties of running java program from other jvm? thxs